# Shell script is not correctly scraping body text from web page

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a shell script where a user can input the IMDb numeric code of a movie (EX: `0076759` corresponds to "Star Wars: A New Hope") from the movie's page URL on the site. My intention with the program is that if the user executes the script:
`bash search_movie 0076759`, the output is as follows:

```
Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)
    Luke Skywalker joins forces with a...[Rest of Plot Summary Text here]
```

This is my current script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# moviedata--Given a movie or TV title, returns a list of matches. If the user
# specifies an IMDb numeric index number, however, returns the synopsis of
# the film instead.

# Remember to install lynx with command: sudo yum install lynx

titleurl="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt"
imdburl="http://www.imdb.com/find?s=tt&exact=true&ref_=fn_tt_ex&q="
tempout="/tmp/moviedata.$$"

# Produce a synopsis of the film.
summarize_film() {    
    grep "<title>" $tempout | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g;s/(more)//'
    grep --color=never -A2 '<h5>Plot:' $tempout | tail -1 | \
    cut -d\< -f1 | fmt | sed 's/^/ /'
    exit 0
}

trap "rm -f $tempout" 0 1 15

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
 echo "Usage: $0 {movie title | movie ID}" >&2
 exit 1
fi

# Checks whether we're asking for a title by IMDb title number
nodigits="$(echo $1 | sed 's/[[:digit:]]*//g')"
if [ $# -eq 1 -a -z "$nodigits" ] ; then
 lynx -source "$titleurl$1/combined" > $tempout
 summarize_film
 exit 0
fi

# It's not an IMDb title number, search for titles.

fixedname="$(echo $@ | tr ' ' '+')" # for the URL
url="$imdburl$fixedname"
lynx -source $imdburl$fixedname > $tempout

# No results:

fail="$(grep --color=never '<h1 class="findHeader">No ' $tempout)"

# If more than one matching title found:

if [ ! -z "$fail" ] ; then
    echo "Failed: no results found for $1"
    exit 1
elif [ ! -z "$(grep '<h1 class="findHeader">Displaying' $tempout)" ] ; then
    grep --color=never '/title/tt' $tempout | \
    sed 's/</\
</g' | \
    grep -vE '(.png|.jpg|>[ ]*$)' | \
    grep -A 1 "a href=" | \
    grep -v '^--$' | \
    sed 's/<a href="\/title\/tt//g;s/<\/a> //' | \
    awk '(NR % 2 == 1) { title=$0 } (NR % 2 == 0) { print title " " $0 }' | \
    sed 's/\/.*>/: /' | \
    sort
fi

exit 0
```

When executing the script, the output gets to the relevant movie page successfully but it does not return the plot summary and also outputs a mess of website tracker info as well
[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if I could get some insight into what I'm doing wrong in my script.

Comment: which part of `html` page do you want to parse? just `title` or some others ?

Comment: Just the title and the plot summary (`<div class="summary_text">`)

Comment: To parse html use html aware tool. Use xmllint or xmlstarlet. [Do not use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all parsing `html` page with `regex` is not the right way to do it, using appropriate parser is a better choice.

Second your script can be much more simpler,

1. have the list of desire `tag`s you want to parse
2. loop over those `tag`s to extract text
3. do what ever you want with text you have saved.

here is a simple **one-liner** to parse `<title` and `<script>`

```
for tag in title script; do lynx -source "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759" | perl -lne "/(?<=<$tag>).*?(?=<)/ && print $&"; done
```

output

```
Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977) - IMDb
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_pre_title"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_post_title"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_pre_icon"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_post_icon"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_pre_css"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_post_css"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
(function(t){ (t.events = t.events || {})["csm_head_pre_ads"] = new Date().getTime(); })(IMDbTimer);
```

or using an array

```
#!/usr/bash
html_tag=(title script)
for tag in ${html_tag[@]}; do
    lynx -source "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759" | \
         perl -lne "/(?<=<$tag>).*?(?=<)/ && print $&"
done
```

here I used **perl** because it has more feature with `regex`.

---

NOTE, if you save the page on disk and then parse it, it would be much better and simple to parse. here is a simple one:

```
# save on disk
lynx -source "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759" > html
# match those two parts you wnat
perl -lne '$/=undef; print $& while /(?:(?<=<title>)|(?<="summary_text">))[^<]+/g' html
```

output:

```
Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977) - IMDb

                Luke Skywalker joins forces with a Jedi Knight, a cocky pilot, a Wookiee and two droids to save the galaxy from the Empire's world-destroying battle station, while also attempting to rescue Princess Leia from the mysterious Darth Vader.
```